# Why is move-assignment operator invoked for lvalue argument?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, assignment-operator, variant, rvalue

I'm currently doing some debugging on our Variant class.
Can someone explain why the compiler selects the move-assignment operator in this particular case? As `testValue` is an lvalue, I would expect the compiler to select the copy assignment... [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment)

```
template <typename T, typename... TN>
template <typename U>
Variant<T, TN...>& Variant<T, TN...>::operator = (U&& a_Value)
{
    // Move value ...
}

template <typename T, typename... TN>
template <typename U, typename... UN>
Variant<T, TN...>& Variant<T, TN...>::operator = (const Variant<U, UN...>& a_Variant)
{
    // Copy data...
}

std::string testValue("test");
Variant<char32_t, std::string> var;
var = testValue; // testValue now becomes empty string
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(U&& a_Value)` is not a rvalue reference, but a forwarding reference.

`U` deduced as `std::string&` in your case.

Move assignment would be something like:

```
template <typename T, typename... TN>
Variant<T, TN...>& Variant<T, TN...>::operator = (Variant<T, TN...>&& rhs)
{
    // Move value ...
}
```

or

```
template <typename T, typename... TN>
template <typename U, typename... UN>
Variant<T, TN...>& Variant<T, TN...>::operator = (Variant<U, UN...>&& rhs)
{
    // Move value ...
}
```

Comment: So, why is ``U`` a forwarding reference?

Comment: @Ben: See interesting [universal-vs-forwarding-references-in-cpp/](https://blog.petrzemek.net/2016/09/17/universal-vs-forwarding-references-in-cpp/). `template <typename T> void f(T&&)` is forwarding reference, accepts everything, versus `void f(std::vector<int>&&)` which accepts only rvalue non const reference of `vector<int>`.